# What are the differences between these array definitions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand the differences between these array definitions:

```
abc=[ 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

and

```
abc=[0;0;0;0;0;0]
```

In C, first definition is

```
int abc[]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

second definition is

```
int [6][1]= {{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0}};
```

Am I correct about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
abc = [1 2 3 4]
```

Is a "row vector".

```
abc = [1 2; 3 4]
```

Is a 2x2 matrix, because semicolons inside brackets separate rows.

```
abc = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Is a 4x1 matrix, aka "column vector". It's a special case of a matrix, really. You can also get it by transposing the corresponding row vector:

```
abc = [1 2 3 4]'
```

(note the quote at the end - this is the transpose)

---

P.S.: Yes, your interpretation to C is correct in this case.

Comment: thx mrs eli. i  am trying to learn matlab, could  you say me  good resource ?

Comment: @ironykchel: the Matlab documentation is pretty good, and Googling "matlab tutorial" should do the rest

Comment: @ironykchel Find interesting problem and try to solve it :) It's the best way to learn, IMHO.
Have you looked at file exchange at matlabcentral webpage? It is sometimes interesting to see how other people solve their problems.

Comment: I'll add that be careful of ' i.e., the complex conjugate transpose operator. If your data is complex, it produces the conjugate transpose. The .' operator produces a non-conjugate transpose if all you wish to do is change the shape of your array as transpose would do. If your array is real, then they are identical operators.

Comment: Matlab is also column-major so it is faster to scan down columns than over rows. Column-major order means that elements along a column are sequential in memory while elements along a row are further apart. Scanning down columns promotes cache efficiency.